# Correct use of "to be far from doing something"

Tags: expressions, idioms

Actually I have two questions:

1 - Is this expression very common in a native environment ( AmE or BrE )?

2 - Are these examples correct ?

- I am so far from who i was yesterday
- I am far from being ready

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can find "far from" as a phrase in most good dictionaries, and it's used as you suggest. I'm not sure what counts as "very common" - it's not odd or wrong but there are many other ways of expressing the same thing: "I'm not ready (yet)", "I'm not even close to being ready", "I'm unready", "I need to get ready", etc. Which you use is a matter of choice.

Comment: It's rather more common these days to say "I'm a long way from <doing something>". Certainly "far from" and "a long way from" are synonyms but the first version sounds a little dated these days.